# Error importing data from module Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a couple scripts that need some common information, so I decided to write that information in python formatting and import it as a module.  However, my scripts now refuse to recognize all of the items.

If I look at the contents of the module using `dir(sumFile)` (where sumFile is how I call the module),  I get the following list.

```
['Cell', 'Isotope', 'Material', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'cellList', 'curCell', 'curMat', 'file', 'libStartNum', 'matList', 'orMode', 'power', 'stepList', 'takenTallyList']
```

where Cell, Isotope, and Material are all classes, and cellList to the end are variables

Now, there should be an item in there called "index", but its not.  Here's a snipit of the module:

```
# 4. ASSORTED FILE INFORMATION 
# Index of 2nd Blank Line: 
index = '47'

# Original File Name: 
file = 'sample.txt' 

# Taken Tally Numbers: 
takenTallyList = [ 
] 

# Origen Type: 
orMode = 'thermal' 

# XS Lib Start Num: 
libStartNum =  '219'
```

So we can see that it reads file, takenTallyList, orMode, and libStartNum, just fine, but refuses to read index.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: When you write ‘module’, do you mean module as a single file, or a package—a directory with `__init__.py` file in it? Also, does your module have an `__all__` entry somewhere? (It's a list of what this module allows to be imported from outside.)

Comment: Its just a single file, not a package.  There is no `__all__` entry anywhere, should there be? formatted

Comment: No, if there's no such entry then everything should be importable… But you can try defining it as ``__all__ = ['index']`` to see what would happen with ``dir()`` behavior.

Comment: No, this isn't a problem with \_\_all\_\_ (its used to limit what is imported when you do `from xyz import *`). And from what you've shown us, index should be there. Are you importing the sumFile.py module you think you are? Is os.path.abspath(sumFile.__file__) the right file?

Comment: No joy, I got the same result from `dir()`

Could the problem be related to the modules?

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for the correction. It was a mistake on my part to think it influences other behavior as well.

Comment: @wnnmaw,`index` is a common name, I would try searching through the file—maybe you're accidentally deleting it somewhere after it's defined? (Although it seems from question that your module doesn't contain any logic, only variable definitions.)

Comment: `os.path.abspath(sumFile.__file__)` returns `'C:\\Python27\\OSDI\\OSDI_InputSum_1.pyc'` which is the correct file.  Also, the file is originally named "OSDI_InputSum_1" without any extension, might this be an issue?

Comment: Yes, I'd try renaming the file to have `.py` extension. In fact, I'm sure it would help! Just checked myself and discovered some strange behavior =)

Comment: Welp, that was easy.... Thanks so much!

Comment: When python loads a .py file, it creates a stripped-down .pyc file to use for faster loading in the future. If the .pyc is newer than the .py, the .pyc is used. Normally, when you edit the .py file, its newer so a new .pyc is created. But this can be a problem if you are copying the file from somewhere else. For instance, if you keep OSDI_InputSum_1.py somewhere else and copy it into C:\Python27\OSDI\, you may find that the .pyc file is newer that the file you copied, so python sticks with the old stale .pyc.

Answer (score 0):

Which objects are accessible in the module is defined in its `__init__.py`.
If `index` is declared in a package within the module and not explicitly exposed, it won't be accessible.